# Is $\sum_{i} \sum_{j} x_{ij} \log(\frac{a_{ij}}{\sum_{i}x_{ij}} +1) $ concave?

Tags: logarithms, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Is $\sum_{i} \sum_{j} x_{ij} \log(\frac{a_{ij}}{\sum_{i}x_{ij}}+1) $ concave for $x_{ij} \in [0,1]$? I know that $\sum_{i} \sum_{j} x_{ij} \log(\frac{a_{ij}}{\sum_{i}x_{ij}})$ is concave for $x_{ij} \in [0,1]$ (It has been proven).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try computing the second derivative for $1$ or $2$ variables? What did you encounter?

Comment: Yes, the second derivative for 1 variable is negative.

Comment: @max_zorn Do you think that I can prove the concavity of multi-variable function from the 1 or 2 variable function?

Comment: Not necessarily but it should give you an idea. I would start with the Hessian for 2 variables.